# GLM feature selection method

Tags: matlab, statistics

I use General Linear Model (GLM) to do feature extraction and to get a beta-matrix. I also got a class-label-matrix. It is a multiple class problem.

Now I want to use t-test to do feature selection based on GLM feature extraction. Can anyone tell me how to write t-test to do this feature selection? Thank you so much!

Comment: Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Anyone can give me a help?

Comment: This question seems more suited to Cross Validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @cnluzon, thank you, I already add the "cross validated" tag. Hope someone can solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the function [`fitglm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitglm.html)? It can fit general linear models and returns p-values and t statistics for all your regressors automatically:

`mdl = fitglm(X,y,'linear','Distribution','normal')`

If you'd prefer calculating the t-tests yourself, you can run a t-test for testing whether your weights are significantly different than 0 by calculating the t-statistic: `beta/SE(beta)` for each of your weights `beta`, where `SE(beta)` is the standard error of your betas (or, the square root of the diagonal of the variance-covariance matrix). You can read more about the t-test for regressors [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/f-statistic-and-t-statistic.html#bty1m3o-1).